# CefSharp 73 close/dispose subprocess when tabbed in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I've build a simple form using CefSharp tabbed in a tabcontrol. Application start with 2 tabpages with 2 urls. One of this site can open new popup in new tabpages, but closing new tabs not kill parent subprocess.

In the main method call

```
 EnablePopup popupok = new EnablePopup();
 browser2.LifeSpanHandler = popupok;
 popupok.popup += Popupallowed;
```

In the LifeSpanHander I used

```
public class EnablePopup : ILifeSpanHandler
{
    public event Action<string> popup;

    public bool DoClose(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void OnAfterCreated(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser)
    {
    }

    public void OnBeforeClose(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser)
    {
    }

    public bool OnBeforePopup(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string targetUrl, string targetFrameName, WindowOpenDisposition targetDisposition, bool userGesture, IPopupFeatures popupFeatures, IWindowInfo windowInfo, IBrowserSettings browserSettings, ref bool noJavascriptAccess, out IWebBrowser newBrowser)
    {
        if (targetUrl.Contains(" my conditions ") == true)
        {
            if (popup != null)
                popup(targetUrl);
        }

        newBrowser = null;
        return true;
    }
}
```

In the handler I use

```
private void Popupallowed(string obj)
    {            
        Invoke(new Action(() => {
            TabPage pop = new TabPage(title);
            prtTabControl.TabPages.Add(pop);
            ChromiumWebBrowser popup = new ChromiumWebBrowser(obj);
            popup.RequestHandler = new DisableNavigate();
            popup.MenuHandler = new DisableMenu();
            ClosePopup exitpopup = new ClosePopup();
            popup.LifeSpanHandler = exitpopup;
            exitpopup.close += Leavepop;
            popup.Parent = prtTabControl.SelectedTab;
            pop.Controls.Add(popup);
            popup.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            popup.Show();
            prtTabControl.SelectedTab = pop;
        }));
    }
```

Intercept other popup

```
public class ClosePopup : ILifeSpanHandler
{
    public event Action<IBrowser> close; //need to intercept javascript window.close to avoid cef.shutdown and application exit

    public bool DoClose(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser)
    {
        if (close != null)
            close(browser);

        return true;
    }

    public void OnAfterCreated(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser)
    {
    }

    public void OnBeforeClose(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser)
    {
    }

    public bool OnBeforePopup(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string targetUrl, string targetFrameName, WindowOpenDisposition targetDisposition, bool userGesture, IPopupFeatures popupFeatures, IWindowInfo windowInfo, IBrowserSettings browserSettings, ref bool noJavascriptAccess, out IWebBrowser newBrowser)
    {
        browser.MainFrame.LoadUrl(targetUrl); //allow navigate in the new tabpage
        newBrowser = null;
        return true;
    }
}
```

If fired window.close Leavepop exit tabpage with

```
    private void Leavepop(IBrowser obj)
    {
        Invoke(new Action(()=> {
            prtTabControl.TabPages.RemoveAt(prtTabControl.SelectedIndex);
            prtTabControl.SelectedTab = tabSito2;
        }));
    }
```

How I can kill supbrocess with tabpage?
Thank you so much.

Comment: You have cancelled the `Close` by returning `true` in `DoClose`. Try removing the `ChromiumWebBrowser` instance from it's parent then calling it's `Dispose` method.

Comment: Alternatively you can call https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-destroywindow passing in the handle returned from http://cefsharp.github.io/api/75.1.x/html/M_CefSharp_IBrowserHost_GetWindowHandle.htm as detailed here https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=17083&p=43352&hilit=destroywindow#p43352

Comment: @amaitland in the `Leavepop` I added  `obj.CloseBrowser(true);` before do close the tabpage and the browsersubprocess end if intercept the javascript `window.close`. How I can reproduce closing custom tabpage clicking X? Any suggestion?

Comment: @amaitland You are right! `DoClose` must to be set to `false` in the both `ILifeSpanHandler`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found! Tabpages must to be disposed instead be removed for kill BrowserSubProcess.exe!